# Density distribution for feature analysis

Tags: feature-engineering, dimensionality-reduction

I trained a ML model on original data with 6373 features, then I trained the same model on compressed data (using autoencoder) and I got an improvement. Finally, I trained the same model on reduced data (using Locally Linear Embedding). The best results are achieved by LLE followed by bottleneck features, and then, original features. I want to perform an ablation study describing the new reduced features using LLE algorithm. I tried to apply PCA and visualize data, but they are too complex to visualize in 2 or 3D. So I tried to plot a density distribution of the 3 best features (chosen based on Random Forest importance), and I got the following:

[image]

From left to right: Original features - Autoencoder features - LLE features

My questions are simple:

1- Can I consider the trend of high and low density for these features as positive impact of LLE or not?

2- How to interpret the first column (original features)?